# Can I limit how much bandwidth is consumed by active directory stuff on windows 7 clients running over 3G

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-7, 3g

We have a number of windows 7 clients on mobile devices. These are connected over 3G (sometimes wifi) to a LAN. Authentication is through active directory. This is consuming bandwidth by constantly keeping in touch with the domain controller.

Is it possible to limit the amount of communication/synchronisation sent by each device to the domain controller? e.g. by placing the 3G laptops in a specific group with a certain group policy?

Other solutions are welcome as well, considering the setup

- windows 7
- always 3G
- sometimes wifi on LAN
- active directory logins
- sometimes someone needs to login to a device that he hasn't logged
  into before

Comment: I'm assuming you are running some sort of VPN over the 3G connection to get connectivity between the Win7 devices, correct? What are you using for this?

Comment: "sometimes someone needs to login to a device that he hasn't logged into before" I hope you don't use roaming profiles!

Comment: @Tom I don't know, it's not my AD. I just want to supply my customer with a solution. I think that specific scenario is only supported when the user has access to wifi

Comment: @Skawt a private access point name limited to specific SIM cards and routed over a leased line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. Read the article [Specifying Group Policy for Slow Link Detection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781031%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
You find the settings in the policies here:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy\Group Policy slow link detection policy
```

You have to define what is considered a slow connection in kbps. The "Windows-traffic" will automaticly reduced.